# Getting StringIndexOutOfBounds exception with Progress Database

Tags: java, relational-database

I am getting the below exception when I am trying to retrieve data from Progress database.

```
  Exception::java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1768)
 at com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressResultSet.reWordAsCountQuery(JdbcProgressResultSet.java:6634)
 at com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressResultSet.calculateRowCount(JdbcProgressResultSet.java:6427)
 at com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressResultSet.initialize(JdbcProgressResultSet.java:157)
 at com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressStatement.getResultSet(JdbcProgressStatement.java:435)
 at com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcProgressPreparedStatement.java:97)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
 at com.esb.service.DBService.handleStatement(DBService.java:992)
```

One thing I noticed is if I put a space at the beginning or end  of the query the query works fine.But this looks strange to me.
Can any one help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also, look at String index out of range: -1 received when translating a SQL map that retrieves data from a Progress database and the SQL statements in the map do not return a result set. (SCI92727): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21543521

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the reply.

Comment: As you mentioned,this issue is seen when the result set is empty.Here I want to know updated version of which component has to be used.Will this be a patch to be applied to database?

Comment: From the page: This has been corrected in Release 4.0 SP3 Patch 20 and higher and Release 4.1 Patch 16 and higher. I would imagine that it will be applied to the JDBC driver, so will be in the client jar. Other than that, I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the info.I will try updating the client jar.

Answer (score 0):

Given this [bug report page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21543521), it looks like you basically need to update to a later release.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the reply.By updating you mean the jar used to connect to progress database has to be updated?

Comment: @user954419: I don't know enough about Progress to say, to be honest - but it sounds quite possible.